# How Can I reload my angluarjs custom directive from outside the angular scope?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have updated a few values for the scope but I need to re-run the whole controller code again, basically reload my directive. I cannot seem to trigger that using   `elementScope.$$childHead.$apply();` as it just updates values in scope doesn't re-load the directive.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: There is probably a better way to design the controller so that it does not need to be re-instantiated. It's hard to help with a coding problem when the question lacks any of the problem code.

Comment: @georgeawg Yes you are right, I actually did just that. I re-designed it in a way that a scope update actually updates the directive. Thank you.

Comment: You should either delete this question or [write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) showing the code you used to solve the proiblem.